# Advanced threat detection vs IP restriction

Tags: security, azure-sql-database

If we configured IP restriction to allow only internal network, then why we need threat detection? 
IP restriction already blocks connections from other resources. Moreover, advanced threat detection is not free.

Comment: I thinks this question is best suited for [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com). The short answer would be that the best defence is multilayered.

Answer (score 0):

Even from your own internal network you can receive  anomalous database activities. Your database could face internal and external threats every day. Threat detection can detect SQL injection attacks and anomalous database access patterns coming from your own internal networks.